# mysql select with changing date based on column

Tags: mysql, select

I have a table of orders, there are two types of orders. "fix" and "new". All orders have an orderDate. I need to order the results of a mysql select in an unusual way.

If the order is type "fix", it will have a due date of the order date PLUS 1 day.

If the order is type "new", it will have a due date of the order date PLUS 2 days.

I need to order by the due date, but the due date is something that does not exist in a column. How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As i read from you question you need to order by due_date
Here is the code orderin by due_date`enter code here`:

```
SELECT 
    *
FROM
    tablename
ORDER BY CASE order_type
    WHEN 'fix' THEN order_date + INTERVAL 1 DAY
    ELSE order_date + INTERVAL 2 DAY
END DESC;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can generate a virtual column based on that conditions and order by that column:

```
SELECT
     CASE order_type
         WHEN 'fix' THEN datecolumn + INTERVAL 1 DAY
         ELSE datecolumn + INTERVAL 2 DAY END order_date
FROM
    tablename
ORDER BY order_date DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

use `case` statement with `date_add()` function:

```
select type, case order.type
                        when 'fix' then date_add(OrderDate,interval 1 DAY)
                        else then date_add(OrderDate,interval 2 DAY)
                   end order_date
from table_name
order by order_date
```